# How can i set execution order of .feature file in specflow?

Tags: visual-studio, xunit, specflow

in my project, I have 2 feature file

abc.feature
xyz.feature

I want to execute it in sequential order.
As of now, those are getting executed in parallel.

Note=> I'm using hooks. for BeforeTestRun method.

Comment: Why do you need them executed in a certain order?

Comment: And which unit test runner are you using?